# How to set our our custom image as icon in mahapps drop down button

Tags: mahapps.metro

I am using the Mahapps drop down button. I am unable to set the image that is local to my application as icon of the drop down button. How to achieve that. Currently am Maintaining my image source like below

```
<BitmapImage
    x:Key="LoginBottom"
    UriSource="pack://application:,,,/oApplication;component/Resources/LoginBottom.png" />
```

after that am refering that image like below

```
<Controls:DropDownButton

                        Icon="{StaticResource LoginBottom}"
                        >
```

But instead of the image am getting the urisource as text. which means whatever text is mentioned in the urisource is being shown in the drop down button.

Comment: did my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `Image` Control with your BitmapImage Resource.

Like so:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton>
    <Controls:DropDownButton.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource LoginBottom}" />
    </Controls:DropDownButton.Icon>
</Controls:DropDownButton>
```

Comment: Am unable to use "DropDownButton.Icon". it shows the property icon was not found.

Comment: Which version of mahapps you are using?
Can you show me your code

Comment: I have uploaded my project here- https://www.zeta-uploader.com/en/836580025 .This is my package detail <package id="MahApps.Metro" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net452" />

Comment: You should use GitHub :s